# Valid use of polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have 2 classes that perform a very similar task, but require different data types passed to them in order to perform those functions.

They both ultimately write to files and have expose a single public method:  `write()`  using the constructor for simple dependency injection.

This is where they differ - 1 class accepts a single object of a specific type, while the other accepts an array of that object type.

Is this a valid case for polymorphism?  I think it can be but tehcnically should not?

How is this situation to be correctly handled i.e. 2 or more classes which perform a very similar function, but in a slightly different way and crucially, require different data types passed in as dependencies?

Comment: Subtype polymorphism applies when types can be unified. Are you willing to accept `void write(object data)` as a signature? (Actually, it can be refined with generics - but the same case of unification holds. Otherwise you end up with an overloaded method with two *different* signatures. Overloading is orthogonal to subtype polymorphism.)

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider the design. How much different are these `write` methods? Could they be replaced with a single implementation using varargs?

Comment: the implementations are very different also.

Answer (score 1):

You need overloaded methods in this case. One which works with single object and other with a number of objects. They should be in the same class.

Here is an easy-to-remember way of when to use what:
1. Overloading is when you need to do **the same thing with different data**
2. Overriding is when you need to do **the same thing with the same data in a different way**

```
public class FileWriter {

    public void write(File from){ // single file
        // magic logic
    }

    public void write(File... from){ // multiple files using varargs
        // magic logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two `Write` methods, one taking a single object and the other taking a List of objects -> I would put both methods on the same class.

If you have one `Write` for each type, I would go for generics.

Introducing a base class wouldn't be my first choice, better to extract the general stuff into another class and use it from different classes (has-a instead of is-a).

Polymorphism is only useful if you have the same method signature but need to do stuff in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer without a particular code sample, but the scenario you've presented fits something similar to a decorator pattern:

```
class X
{
    public void doSomething(int number) { ... }
};

class XForCollections
{
    public XForCollections(X x) { ... }

    public void doSomething(int[] numbers) { ... }
};
```

Note, that it's not really a decorator, as `XForCollection` doesn't inherit `X`.

Comment: This also seems like a use case for the composite pattern but the question is too vague to say for sure.

Comment: @Tom we can use simple varargs, instead ? :-)

Comment: @LittleChild that's exactly what I suggested in a comment under this very question ;)

Comment: @Tom Good point. Either way not much of polymorphism in this particular case.

Comment: @Tom Read just now :-D

Answer (score 1):

**Polymorphism** – means the ability of a single variable of a given type to be used to reference objects of
different types, and automatically call the method that is specific to the type of object the variable references. In a
nutshell, polymorphism is a bottom-up method call. **The benefit of polymorphism is that it is very easy to add new
classes of derived objects without breaking the calling code**  that uses the polymorphic classes or interfaces. When you send a message to an object even though you
don’t know what specific type it is, and the right thing happens, that’s called ***polymorphism***. The process used by
object-oriented programming languages to implement polymorphism is called ***dynamic binding***.

Example:

**Launcher**

```
    private void init() {
        //client or calling code
        double dim = 5.0; //i.e. 5 meters radius or width
        List<Shape> listShapes = new ArrayList<Shape>(20);
        Shape s = new Circle();
        listShapes.add(s); //add circle
        s = new Square();
        listShapes.add(s); //add square
        getTotArea (listShapes,dim); //returns 78.5+25.0=103.5
        //Later on, if you decide to add a half circle then define
        //a HalfCircle class, which extends Circle and then provide an
        //area(). method but your called method getTotArea(...) remains
        //same. 
        }

    /** called method: method which adds up areas of various
     ** shapes supplied to it.
     **/
    public double getTotArea(List<Shape> listShapes, double dim){
        Iterator<Shape> it = listShapes.iterator();
        double totalArea = 0.0;
        //loop through different shapes
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Shape s = (Shape) it.next();
            totalArea += s.area(dim); //polymorphic method call
        }
        return totalArea ;
    }
}
```

**Shape**

```
public abstract class Shape {
    protected abstract double area(double dim);
}
```

**Square**

```
public class Square extends Shape{

    @Override
    protected double area(double dim) {
        return dim*dim;
    }
}
```

**Circle**

```
public class Circle extends Shape{

    @Override
    protected double area(double dim) {
        return Math.PI*dim*dim;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use an abstract generic superclass with the common stuff.

If you want `WriterA` that writes an argument of type `ArgA`, and  `WriterB` that writes an argument of type `ArgB`, you'll make

- an abstract `Writer<T>` with all of the common stuff in it, and an abstract method such as `public void write(T arg)`
- `WriterA` that extends `Writer<ArgA>`
- `WriterB` that extends `Writer<ArgB>`

Answer (score 1):

Say you have this:

```
class A{
    void write(int a){}
}

class B{
    void write(int[] a){}
}
```

Since you say the implementations for those methods vary deeply between each other, then varargs probably wouldn't be a suitable option. To simplify things, do this::

```
class WriteStuff{
    void write(int a){}
    void write(int[] a){}
}
```

This would let you attain a higher level of cohesion for your classes. Polymorphism isn't really necessary here.

Then again, it's really too little information to go on with. You should probably write up some example code.